# How to tracking email opens in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics-4

In Universal Analytics there's [Email Tracking - Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/email) for tracking email actions.
But not in the [GA4 document](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4).

Will this kind of use case be supported by GA4 in the future?
Or there is an alternative that I didn't find?

Thanks. :)

Comment: The feeling when you find your question on stackoverflow with 0 answers... What did you implement in the end?

Comment: The feeling when you find your question on stack Ooverflow with 0 answers. What did you implement in the end?

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part is that GA4 MP only supports POST request, so it would be difficult to use GA4 MP directly in the email as what we did with UA MP.

However, GA4 itself still supports both GET/POST requests, this means, you can still manually create a GET request like:

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect?v=2&tid=G-XXXXXXXXX&cid=TEST123&en=email_open
```

Then embed it in your email with an img tag, just like what we used to do with UA.

During our test, the event itself can be correctly received and processed by GA4, however user_properties values seem not be processed correctly. Nevertheless, if you only want to have a email_open count, this will work as a workaround at least for now.